# 3D Plot using data from a .dat file

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Suppose I have a .dat file, that I could easily manage to import it and it read as below

```
data = {{0.`, 1.5`, 32.`, 4.`}, {0.01`, 13.339967195548438`, 
  43.07461560857787`, 6.505586235757622`}, {0.02`, 
  26.576707615610186`, 62.27984871710982`, 
  14.52957307602648`}, {0.03`, 43.92146166445253`, 88.22533168346912`,
   33.35986308123866`}, {999.97`, 4.852152291519739`, 
  20.914352068678742`, 78.65196295800204`}, {999.98`, 
  11.498870411172586`, 23.281707241849393`, 
  81.49717171318073`}, {999.99`, 17.163630489595015`, 
  23.943758603766856`, 85.08665301847587`}, {1000.`, 
  21.44200492399224`, 22.39480828216125`, 88.75135651276551`}}
```

Now, I need to plot a 3D graph using data available in **column-2** vs **column-3** vs **column-4**. How do I do that?

Comment: `ListLinePlot3D[data[[All, 2 ;; 4]]]` ?

Comment: For v13, you have commands available (such as ListPointPlot3D, ListLinePlot3D, ListSurfacePlot3D) for which you can look up information in the docs.

Comment: If you have an array of 4 data points such as myData= {{a,b,c,d},{d,e,f,g},...{p,q,r,s}} and you want to plot the fourth element as a function of the second and third, then extract second, third, and fourth and use `ListPlot3D[myData[[All,2;;]]]`

Comment: `data[[All,2;;4]] // Point // Graphics3D` ?

Comment: I need to Plot only the last 100 data from the .dat file. How do I choose that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the toy-model set you provided and assume that you want to plot the last three.

The way to pick them

```
lastthree = data[[6 ;;]]
```

> [image: lastthree]

One way to plot them is using [`ListPointPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html)

```
ListPointPlot3D[lastthree, PlotRange -> All, 
 LabelingFunction -> Callout, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

> [image: ListPointPlot3D]

And a couple of more based on [`ListPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) and [`ListLinePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot3D.html)

```
ListPlot3D[lastthree, PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot3D[lastthree, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: plot1]

> [image: plot2]

Have fun!

Comment: I am using Mathematica 12.0. And ListLinePlot3D seems to be absent there. How do I join the points if I am using ListPointPlot3D?

Comment: @user84456 I have been trying to find an easy way to do it but I have not been able to do so. Sorry!